# CollectionView show cells if equal to int Columns value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, xcode8

I have a collectionView to show sub categories with icons from database using json it works fine but notice recently it has a big problem. if values in database is equal to "intColumns" it works fine for example if value 2 and "intColumns = 3" it showing noting. but if values in database =3  it showing the 3 cells .

and if values in database = 5 it is only showing 3 cells.

what is the problem here?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;


GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
// Enable test ads on simulators.
request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];

windowSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
common = [[CommonFramework alloc]init];

categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"subcategory",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"selectedMainCategory"]]]];
selectedCategory = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"selectedMainCategory"]];
selectedCategoryIndex = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[selectedCategory objectForKey:@"id"]];
[self loadCategory];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
intColumns = 3;

self.navigationItem.title = [selectedCategory valueForKey:@"title"];
[self.gridView registerClass:[GridCell class] 
forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GridCell"];
[self loadCategory];


}


*/
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return intColumns;
 }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView 
*)collectionView {
return [categoryArray count] / intColumns;
}


 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:
 (UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:
 (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
statusBarOrientation])) {
    return CGSizeMake(windowSize.size.width/intColumns*2, 100);
 }
//NSLog(@"Grid Width : %i", round(_gridView.frame.size.width /intColumns));

return CGSizeMake( windowSize.size.width/intColumns - 20 , 100.f);
}



- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
// Setup cell identifier
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"GridCell";

GridCell *cell = [collectionView 
dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier 
forIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect cellFrame = cell.frame;
cellFrame.size.width = windowSize.size.width / intColumns -20;
cellFrame.size.height = 100;
cell.frame = cellFrame;
if ([cell subviews]){
    for (UIView *subview in [cell subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

int itemIndex = indexPath.row + (intColumns * indexPath.section);

UIView *CellView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 
cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

UIImageView *imgIcon = [[UIImageView 
alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((CellView.frame.size.width/2) - (30), 0, 60, 
60)];



  NSString *documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains 
 (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *imagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[categoryArray objectAtIndex:itemIndex] 
valueForKey:@"icon"]]];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
bool success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath: imagePath];

if (!success)
{

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                   ^{
                       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",common.IMAGE_ICON,[[categoryArray objectAtIndex:itemIndex] valueForKey:@"icon"]]]]];



                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                      ^{
                                          if(image!=nil)
                                          {
                                              NSString *documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                                              NSLog(@"Image Path : %@",common.IMAGE_ICON);
                                              //[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:imagePath options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];

                                              [self addSkipBackupAttributeToPath:[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",common.IMAGE_ICON,[[categoryArray objectAtIndex:itemIndex] valueForKey:@"icon"]]]];

                                              [imgIcon setImage:image];

                                              //                                                  [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                                          }
                                      });
                   });
}
else
{
    [imgIcon setImage: [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]]]];
}




[CellView addSubview:imgIcon];

// NSLog(@"Row - %i Sec - %i",indexPath.row,indexPath.section);

NSString *title =  [[categoryArray objectAtIndex:itemIndex] objectForKey:@"title"];

UILabel *fromLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,65, CellView.frame.size.width, 18)];
fromLabel.text = title;
fromLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
fromLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueW23foSKY-Bd" size:12.0 ];
//[fromLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Aral" size:10]];
[CellView addSubview:fromLabel];

[cell addSubview:CellView];

// Return the cell
return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
intColumns = 3
```

So `numberOfItemsInSection` returns `3`

Then if `[categoryArray count]` equals `5`, your `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` is returning:

```
return [categoryArray count] / intColumns;
```

or

```
return 5 / 3;
```

So... what is `5 / 3`? It is `1`, because you are doing integer division. Would you want to return `1.666666` for number of Sections?

Most likely, for `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`, you want to:

```
return ceil((double)[categoryArray count] / (double)intColumns);
```

Comment: Then you'll need to provide a bit more information... If you have 5 values, do you get 2 sections but see only 1 row of 3 cells? Do you only see 1 section? Have you stepped through in debug to see if you're getting the values you're expecting?

Comment: yes i get only only one row of 3 cells and missing 2 cells, what about add 1 if [categoryArray count] is odd number. how to do it?

Comment: Difficult to say... If you changed `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` as indicated, it should now be returning `2` if you have 5 values... Is it? If so, and you are also returning `3` for `numberOfItemsInSection`, you have another problem, because it will be looking for the 6th item, but you have only 5 values. So... step through in debug and check your data.

Comment: now app is crashed when change it to return 2;
for test 5 values

Comment: Yes - because you have `5` items you want `2` sections (rows)... and you are returning `3` for `numberOfItemsInSection` for both sections... `2 x 3` equals `6`, but you only have `5` items. You have to account for that. I'm not designing your app, so I don't know what you want to have happen in that case - do you want "empty" cells? do you want "placeholder" cells? do you want a different layout for the last row if it has fewer cells than `intColumns`?